# Theres no bottom padding in my web page

Tags: css, margin

I'm Having Trouble with my Web Page: There is no bottom padding and it makes my website look weird. I have tried changing the body, and html to margin-bottom: 100px but it does not seem to work. This always seems to happen when I add outsourced navigation bars.

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
html, body { margin: 0; padding:0px;}
        body { margin: 5px; background: #f2f2f2; }
        ul.menu { margin: 50px auto 0 auto; }
    .menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

/* Menu */
.menu { 
    height: 40px;
    width: 905px;

    background: #4c4e5a;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4c4e5a 0%,#2c2d33 100%);

    border:#8fde62 medium solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}

/* Links */

.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin: 6px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;

    border-left: 1px solid #393942;
    border-right: 1px solid #4f5058;

    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;

    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);

    -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }

.menu li:hover > a { color: #8fde62; }

/* Sub Menu */

.menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;

    opacity: 0;

    background: #1f2024;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }

.menu ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 36px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 40px;
    margin: 0;

    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}

.menu ul li:last-child a { border: none; }

#wrapper{
    width:900px;
    height:auto;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;

    }
#xboxcard{
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#4c4e5a;
    border:#8fde62 medium solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    }
#rightcontent{
    width:575px;
    height:342px;
    background-color:#4c4e5a;
    border:#8fde62 medium solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    float:right;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:495px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;

    }   
#step1{
    width:245px;
    height:250px;
    position:absolute;
    top:550px;
    left:180px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color:#4c4e5a;
    border:#8fde62 medium solid;

    }
```

HTML

```
<body>
<ul class="menu">

    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Claim</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Proof</a></li>

</ul> <!-- end .menu -->

<div id="wrapper">

    <img src="#" alt="#"  height="342" width="245" style="  background-color:#4c4e5a;
    border:#8fde62 medium solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
  " />
        <div id="rightcontent">
        <h1>This is Some right content!</h1>
        </div>
            <div id="step1">
            </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this your css...

```
#wrapper {
margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

or however many pixels you want the bottom margin to have

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding padding to the body element?

```
body{
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I setup a jsfiddle for your code to take a look, I tweaked some things, check it out and see what you find useful: http://jsfiddle.net/cVLqu/

Biggest recommendation here is:

```
position: relative;
```

on the wrapper and the boxes inside it, that way they expand the wrapper instead of floating around freely.

Also check out this post on css-tricks.com, I found it really helpful:
http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/